# Telemetry server using boost::signals2

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build a telemetry server for one of my projects, which connects a raspberry pi with my local computer. My idea was to have a request driven server, which then captures the required data. Therefore I'm using boost:signals2, to provide the mapping between names and the approriate functions.

The example code below shows the problem that I experience:
*invalid use of non-static member function*

I googled a lot, but somehow I did not get it working.
The "solution" I found was std::bind, but it more or less generates similar output.

How can I get it working? Or do I need a different approach?

http://cpp.sh/9zbtu

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>

class message{
    private:
    std::string data;
    
    public:
    void setMessage(std::string mes){data = mes;};
    std::string getMessage(){return data;};
};

class telemetry{
    public:
    boost::ptr_map< std::string, boost::signals2::signal<std::string ()>> container;
};

    
    
int main()
{
    message A, B;
    A.setMessage("AAA");
    B.setMessage("BBB");
    
    telemetry T;
    T.container["A"].connect(A.getMessage);
    T.container["B"].connect(B.getMessage);
    
    std::cout << "A: " << T.container["A"]() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B: " << T.container["B"]() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this error is related to how class methods work.

The address for the code that executes the method is `&message::getMessage`. But this isn't a function pointer because a class has both *code* and *data*, and this is only the address to the code.

To execute the method, you need both the address of the method, and the address of the class data:

```cpp
std::string (message::*code)() = &message::getMessage; 
message* data = &A;
std::cout << (data->*code)();
```

Anyway, the point is that you can't treat a class method like a function pointer, it has to be bound to the data somehow.

Luckily, `boost::signals2::signal::connect` doesn't take in a function pointer or a pointer-to-member. It takes a `boost::function`, which is a class that wraps class methods and even bind data or arguments to it. `boost::bind` can help you bind the method to the data and return a `boost::function`:

```cpp
T.container["A"].connect(boost::bind(&message::getMessage, A));
T.container["B"].connect(boost::bind(&message::getMessage, B));
```

If you're using C++11 or above though, you can forget all that, because you can pass a [lamba](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```cpp
T.container["A"].connect([&A](){ return A.getMessage(); });
T.container["B"].connect([&B](){ return B.getMessage(); });
```

Lambas are great because they're built-in syntax that you can pass any kind data into, references, values, etc., and represent any kind of code snippet, not just a predefined function or class method. And you can pass them to `boost::function` (or in C++11, `std::function` because they adopted it into the standard).

Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/5rabe1

Comment: I already tried something like this, but obviously made something wrong. With your help I got it wokring now. I modifed the code a bit, to better fit the programm sturcture it self. Maybe it's helpful someone else as well: http://cpp.sh/7w2mz

Thanks a lot!